# Docker. Symlink INSIDE context not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, symlink, php-deployer

I've simplified setup for demonstration purposes, but I don't understand why this issue happens. What do I miss.

Project folder content

```
current -> releases/21
releases
```

inside `releases/21` project with `docker-compose.yml` is located.

Here is the abridged version of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        build:
            context: ../
            dockerfile: ./current/docker/app.docker
```

Of course, `app.docker` is there.

And still I receive this error

```
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: current/docker/app.docker
```

After running `docker-compose up -d` in the `<project_folder>/current`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with an absolute path.

Something like this will work, but I still feel, that it's not a solution

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        build:
            context: /var/www/<project-name>
            dockerfile: ./current/docker/app.docker
```